"se prendre des masques"
En lisant la traduction par André Markowicz de L'adolescent de Dostoïesvki, j'ai été surpris par ce passage :

Moi-même ces sourires, ils me déplaisaient, et aussi visiblement, le fait qu'elle se prenait des masques.

Je ne connaissais pas l'expression "se prendre des masques" et je ne l'aurais pas comprise sans avoir le contexte. Existe-t-elle ou est-ce une invention d'André Markowicz?
En russe:

Мне же лично очень не нравились эти улыбки ее и то, что она всегда видимо подделывала лицо.

À la place de "le fait qu'elle se prenait des masques", j'aurais traduit par "le fait qu'elle se composait toujours le visage".

Je pense que tu veux dire j'ai été surpris plutôt que heurté.

@jlliagre J'ai édité ma question, merci!

Markowicz a la réputation d'être un excellent traducteur, mais, outre le fait que  les premières années de sa vie il a parlé russe, et ensuite parlé français avec son père dont le français n'était pas non plus la langue maternelle, il faut garder  en tête quand on lit une traduction de Markowicz les principes qui régissent ses traductions.  Il a dit  :  « Le traducteur est un imposteur » (voir cet article qui peut aider à comprendre une traduction de  Markowicz).

Extrait du même article :  « Selon lui, le texte produit par le traducteur est rempli d’intentions qui diffèrent de celles de l’auteur. André Markowicz considère ainsi la traduction comme une interprétation et comme une création,... ».   Pour moi la seule réponse possible à la question serait qu'il est normal de rencontrer dans les traductions de  Markowicz des expressions françaises qui sont de la création du traducteur et qui ne sont pas non plus une traduction mot à mot du russe. Ce n'est pas une question de langue française per se, mais de savoir pourquoi  Markowicz a traduit ainsi.

@None cela dit, lorsque j'ouvre un livre intitulé "L'adolescent, F. Dostoievski (traduit du russe par A. Markowicz)" je trouve normal de lire un texte français, compréhensible par un français sans l'aide d'un manuel de déchiffrement. Ce qui n'est pas le cas de la phrase postée ici.

@FrançoisJurain Exagéré le « manuel de déchiffrement »,  le contexte permet de comprendre. Si on lit du Markowicz il faut savoir ce qui sous-tend son œuvre (je n'ose dire ses traductions), si on n'aime les principes qui le guident il existe d'autres traductions de l’œuvre de  Dostoïesvki. « Les textes que je traduis n’ont pas été pensés en langue française, donc ils ne doivent pas répondre à des règles d’une langue littéraire française préétablies.  » Extrait d'une interview.

Vouloir répondre à cette question revient à donner son opinion sur une traduction dont l'auteur a clairement défini les principes qui le guident.

@None est-ce que le VTC est de toi? La question est 100% sur la langue française et n'a rien d'opinion-based: juste clarifier le sens (figuré) de "elle se prenait des masques" et préciser si c'est idiomatique. Le fait que je me permette 1/2 phrase d'opinion dans ma réponse n'implique pas que ce soit principalement cela qui intéresse l'OP.

@None Je ne crois pas que des considérations générales sur (et par) le traducteur (lequel a traduit des dizaines de livres, dont certains font des centaines de pages) aident à éclairer un passage précis. Sans doute A. M. parle mieux le russe que moi, pourtant j'ai quelques passages en tête où je suis sûr qu'il a fait un contresens (ce qui n'enlève rien ni à son mérite ni à l'estime qu'on puisse lui porter) - je pourrais argumenter, mais ça me semble hors-sujet. Je pose une question de français et le russe n'est ici qu'à titre indicatif (car, ici, je le comprends mieux que le français).

Je ne vois aucune véritable demande d'éclaircissement, puisque il est écrit: «  je ne l'aurais pas comprise sans avoir le contexte.  » c'est bien que la phrase est comprise. Pour moi ce qui ressort de la question telle qu'elle est posée c'est une validation (un avis) sur la traduction de Markowicz et je ne pense pas que ce soit bien à sa place ici. Tout passage d'une traduction est éclairé par les intentions ouvertement déclarées du traducteur quand il a fait cette traduction.

@None Non, vous vous trompez. J'aurais pu poser la même question sans le russe. Il m'arrive de rencontrer un mot que je ne connais pas et d'espérer deviner son sens grâce au contexte, j'espère que SE est alors bien un site sur lequel je peux avoir confirmation ou infirmation de ce que je crois avoir deviné. Ça m'est encore arrivé en russe il y a quelques jours et je me suis rendu compte que j'avais mal deviné. Par ailleurs, même si j'ai bien deviné, la question reste entière : est-ce une expression inventée ou utilisée plus ou moins couramment?

Oui c'est une invention du traducteur. L'expression idiomatique est elle semblait porter un masque ou elle semblait masquer son expression:  la comparaison est intéressante en soi et je le trouve malvenu d'innover en me mettant ainsi à la devine.
Pour reconstituer ce sens, j'utilise la même méthode que pour ma précédente réponse au sujet du même roman, faire mouliner Gougueule Transe-latte du russe vers les langues que je sais déchiffrer:

en français: Personnellement, je n’aimais pas vraiment ses sourires et le fait qu’elle semblait toujours simuler son visage.
en anglais: Personally, I really didn’t like her smiles and the fact that she always seemed to be faking her face.
en allemand: Ich persönlich mochte ihr Lächeln und die Tatsache, dass sie immer ihr Gesicht zu verfälschen schien, überhaupt nicht.
en italien: Personalmente non mi piacevano davvero quei suoi sorrisi e il fatto che sembrasse sempre fingere.

Les 4 phrases ont le même sens, que je rendrais ainsi en français:

"Pour ma part, je trouvais quelque chose de déplaisant à ses sourires
et au fait que l'expression de son visage semblait toujours
factice."

C'est quasi identique à la proposition de l'OP, "[le] fait qu'elle se composait toujours le visage". Possiblement (je ne connais du russe que ce que ru.Wkt m'en dit), GT a manqué une traduction plus juste du genre "je voyais de la fausseté dans son expression", ce qui expliquerait qu'A. M. ait ajouté l'adverbe visiblement. En tel cas, je choisirais

"l'expression de son visage m'apparaissait toujours factice."


Translate? On peut aussi dire traduire, non?

@Frank ben... c'est pas moi qui baptise leurs applis, à ces Gougueule people.

Ils affichent "translate" sur la version française?

Le "visiblement" correspond à видимо; j'y vois (mais je peux me tromper) plutôt une nuance d'atténuation ("apparemment") mais ça ne me semble pas justifier de changer la construction de la phrase en modifiant le sujet (en russe c'est bien elle le sujet) - je veux dire qu'on aurait pu avoir même phrase en russe sans видимо et ça me gêne un peu de chambouler la traduction simplement pour avoir ajouté un petit mot "facultatif". Ce n'est bien sûr qu'un détail.

@Bruno Je vois; de là vient peut-être qu'A. M. ait choisi une forme pronominale. Autres possibilités conservant elle comme sujet:  "le fait qu'elle paraissait { composer | travailler | ajuster | déguiser | contrôler } en permanence l'expression de son visage". Ou, dans la ligne des propositions de GT: "le fait qu'elle {semblait | paraissait} toujours présenter un visage faux".

Alternative dans la même veine  : "l'expression de son visage manquait toujours de naturel".
